# Is there an equivalent to a Forest Plot that does not use an Odds Ratio?

Tags: p-value, sample-size, meta-analysis, odds-ratio, forest-plot

I am performing a meta-analysis. Most of my data does not have an odds ratio with a Confidence Interval. The majority of the studies I have included in my meta-analysis only have a p-value for a particular question with a sample size. Can I create a plot with only the sample size and p-values for each study? Is it possible to have a meta-analysis without a Forest Plot based on Odds Ratios?

Answer (score 1):

Just to clear up a possible mis-conception here first there is no requirement to have odds ratios to draw a forest plot you just need an effect size with its confidence interval.

I think what you are searching for is the albatross plot first
suggested by Harrison and colleagues in an article entitled "The albatross plot: A novel graphical tool for presenting the results of diversely reported studies in a systematic review" in Research Synthesis Methods 2017 (8) pages 281 to 289. Fortunately it seems to be open access [here](https://doi.org/10.1002/jrsm.1239). Basically the plot consists of plotting the transformed $p$-values on the $x$-axis and the transformed sample sizes on the $y$-axis. It is then possible to superimpose contours of constant effect size.

I believe the authors made available code for Stata although I do not use Stata so cannot confirm that. It is also implemented in R in the [metap package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=metap). Disclaimer: I am the author of that R package.